# Is there a way to have Javascript throw an error when a new property is added to a given object?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

[Object.preventExtensions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/preventExtensions) and [Object.seal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) prevent unknown properties from being added to an object, but those attributions silently fail instead of throwing an error. Is there a way to force them to be errors?

```
var myObj = Object.seal({});
try{
    myObj.someProp = 17;
    console.log("I don't want to reach this message");
}catch(err){
    console.log("I want an error to occur instead.")
    console.log("Or at least get a warning somewhere.");
}
```

I tested this in Chrome 19 and Firefox 9. I wouldn't mind browser-specific solutions either, since I would only need this during development.

Comment: For me in Chrome, `Object.preventExtensions` does indeed throw an exception when you try to add a property.

Comment: @torazaburo: Are you using strict mode? It only works with strict mode.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If strict mode is an option, Object.seal seems to do the trick (at least in Firefox):

> Attempting to delete or add properties to a sealed object, or to convert a data property to accessor or vice versa, will fail, either silently or by throwing a TypeError (most commonly, although not exclusively, when in strict mode code).

Works pretty good: http://jsfiddle.net/yVWr6/

(btw: works the same for preventExtensions())

Answer (score 1):

According to the [MDN documentation for `Object.seal()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/seal) (and [`Object.freeze()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)) if you enable strict mode then a TypeError will be thrown when attempting to modify a sealed object:

```javascript
function go() {
  'use strict';
  var x = {};
  Object.seal(x);
  x.foo = 123;
}
go(); // => TypeError: Can't add property foo, object is not extensible
```